# Duplicate Oracle Database from .BKP files - getting "multitenant container database not set up properly"

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I have a regular Oracle 12c database already created, named ECLS. I've been given a pile of .BKP files, not from this database, and have been told to replace everything in ECLS with the contents of these files.

With the files, I was also told to use this command to do it:

```
RMAN> duplicate database to ECLS backup location '/u01/dumpfilesgohere';
```

No other directions were provided.

I found that my database needs to be an auxiliary with nothing mounted. So I did the following:

```
$ sqlplus / as sysdba
SQL> shutdown immediate;
SQL> startup nomount;
SQL> exit
$ rman auxiliary /
RMAN> duplicate database to ECLS backup location '/u01/dumpfilesgohere';
```

This looks like it's working properly for the first few seconds... it says that it's able to restore the control files from the BKP files. But then it ends up failing. Here's the last few lines before the failure:

```
contents of Memory Script:
{
   sql clone "alter system set  db_name =
 ''ECLS'' comment=
 ''Reset to original value by RMAN'' scope=spfile";
   sql clone "alter system reset  db_unique_name scope=spfile";
   shutdown clone immediate;
}
executing Memory Script

sql statement: alter system set  db_name =  ''ECLS'' comment= ''Reset to original value by RMAN'' scope=spfile

sql statement: alter system reset  db_unique_name scope=spfile

Oracle instance shut down
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-03002: failure of Duplicate Db command at 01/30/2017 14:59:06
RMAN-05501: aborting duplication of target database
RMAN-03015: error occurred in stored script Memory Script
RMAN-06136: ORACLE error from auxiliary database: ORA-65093: multitenant container database not set up properly
```

What am I doing wrong? What files do I need to change to get this error message to stop occurring?

Alternatively... if my whole database install isn't going to work, can someone tell me what I need to do differently when reinstalling the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> #### 65093, 00000, "multitenant container database not set up properly"
>
> **Cause:**  An attempt was made to open a multitenant container database without
>               the correct parameter set for a multitenant container database in
>               the initialization parameter file.
>
> **Action:** Set the 'enable_pluggable_database=true' parameter for the 
>               multitenant container database in the initialization parameter file
>               and restart the database.

By default `ENABLE_PLUGGABLE_DATABASE` is set to `FALSE`. We need to set this parameter to `TRUE` before creating CDB.

```
RAMN>duplicate database to ECLS
    SPFILE
    set enable_pluggable_database=true
 backup location '/u01/dumpfilesgohere';
```

Comment: I needed to put `true` in single quotes for it to accept it. Now it's giving me this error message: `DUPLICATE without TARGET connection when auxiliary instance is started with spfile cannot use SPFILE clause`.

Comment: Place this parameter in pfile(probably initECLS.ora file) in your database and restart it with pfile in nomount mode.

Comment: This line is already present in initECLS.ora: `*.enable_pluggable_database=true`, and as I showed in my question, I am starting up the database using `startup nomount` in sqlplus.

Comment: It uses spfile, if present, by default while starting up the instance. So either you have to rename the spfile to some other name or have to specify init.ora file explicitly as `SQL> startup pfile='/path/to/pfile.ora' nomount`

Comment: Thanks for that! I've gotten further along now. Now I'm getting this error message: `RMAN-05001: auxiliary file name F:\ORADATA\[...]\DATAFILE\O1_MF_OEM_TEST_D14SM11V_.DBF conflicts with a file used by the target database`. It repeats that message 67 times, and says its aborting duplication. If you know the solution, I'd love to hear it. I'll try to research it a bit and ask another question here if I find nothing.

Comment: You need to specify `NOFILENAMECHECK` after duplicate command. I forgot to mention before. Details are here -https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/backup.102/b14194/rcmsynta028.htm

Comment: Thanks - I got a bit concerned... how much hard drive space is this going to take up? The machine that I'm cloning to has a 200 GB database right now (which I'm hoping will be overwritten by the duplicate command) and the database being duplicated takes up 200 GB, but the machine only has 100 GB free. Will the two sets of database files exist side by side, meaning I'll need another 100 GB of free space, or can I duplicate and it'll be fine? Can I just try and see what happens... or might I end up corrupting something and be left in an unrecoverable state?

Comment: Thanks for the help you've offered so far - I get 2.5 hours into the restore, but then I end up with issues that I think are related to the fact the .BKP files come from Windows but are being used on Linux. Do you know how to handle that fact? I asked a separate question here, since it's not particularly related to the question this post was originally about: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/163074/115871